# Accessing Javascript Created Structure Form Fields in Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm using an imported Javascript code snippet in one of my forms to create a dynamic entry section (you can press the + button to add a line and the - button to remove a line) where an office may have multiple different contact people.  Here is the applicable code for that if you'll need that (but this does work correctly as is so it is not the problem):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var ROWCOUNT = 0;
function add_contact_fields(contactData) {
    if (typeof contactData === 'object') {} else {
    
        ROWCOUNT = ROWCOUNT+1;
        
        contactData = {
                    id: 'A'+ROWCOUNT,
            cFirstName: '',
             cLastName: '',
                cTitle: '',
                cPhone: '',
                cEmail: ''
        }
    }

    var contactRow = document.createElement("div");
    contactRow.setAttribute("class", "form-group row contact-field-wrapper");
    contactRow.innerHTML = ''+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="form-group required">'+
    '       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cFirstName'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cFirstName]" value="'+contactData.cFirstName+'" placeholder="First Name" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="form-group required">'+
    '       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cLastName'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cLastName]" value="'+contactData.cLastName+'" placeholder="Last Name" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="form-group required">'+
    '       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cTitle'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cTitle]" value="'+contactData.cTitle+'" placeholder="Title/Role" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="form-group required">'+
    '       <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="cPhone'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cPhone]" value="'+contactData.cPhone+'" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="12" required="true" data-rule-pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" data-msg-pattern="Please Enter your Phone Number in xxx-xxx-xxxx Format" data-rule-maxlength="12" data-rule-required="true">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="form-group required">'+
    '       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="cEmail'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cEmail]" value="'+contactData.cEmail+'" placeholder="Email" data-rule-email="true" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
    '   <div class="input-group-btn">'+
    '       <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_contact_fields(this);">'+
    '           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>'+
    '       </button>'+
    '   </div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="clear"></div>';
    
    document.getElementById('contact_fields').appendChild(contactRow);

}

function remove_contact_fields(el) {
    el.closest(".contact-field-wrapper").remove();
}
</script>
```

The form works fine and if I dump the form variables I can see the form variable names and their data:

[image: Form data dump]

**My problem though is that I can't seem to access the form values for that section of code.**  For example, this **works**:  `<cfoutput>#form.address#</cfoutput>`  but this does **not** work (*Element CONTACT is undefined*):  `<cfoutput>#form.CONTACT[1][CEMAIL]#</cfoutput>`

I think that it probably has to do with the fact that ColdFusion sees that as some kind of structure or array, however, I'm admittedly pretty weak with those.  I tried using this snippet of code as well, however, it also doesn't work (throws an error):

```
<cfloop index="i" list="#FORM['cFirstName[]']#">    
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aFirstName,"#i#")>
</cfloop>
 <cfloop index="i" list="#FORM['cLastName[]']#">    
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aLastName,"#i#")>
</cfloop>
  <cfloop index="i" list="#FORM['cTitle[]']#">    
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aTitle,"#i#")>
</cfloop>
  <cfloop index="i" list="#FORM['cPhone[]']#">    
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aPhone,"#i#")>
</cfloop>
  <cfloop index="i" list="#FORM['cEmail[]']#">    
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aEmail,"#i#")>
</cfloop>
  
 </cfoutput>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aFirstName)#" >

    <cfoutput>#aFirstName[i]# - #aLastName[i]# - #aTitle[i]# - #aPhone[i]# - #aEmail[i]#</cfoutput><br>

</cfloop>
```

So I'm kind of stuck.  I obviously need to be able to access those variables in order to process them (i.e. save them in a table) but I'm not sure how to do that at this point.  Does anyone have any suggestions or code snippets that I could try?

Comment: Just an observation... Do you really need all the gobbledygook that javascript adds to the name of the form field? It would throw me off too, syntactically. What's wrong with `Email1`, `Email2`, etc.? Much simpler and easier to follow during a loop.

Comment: They keys in your Form scope are text values. When you try to access their values in the above example where it’s failing, it’s because you’re referencing them by array/struct notation. <cfoutput>#form.[“CONTACT[1][CEMAIL]”]#</cfoutput> should work. But if you need to iterate over an array, on submit, you could use JavaScript to create an array of the entries, pack it as JSON into a hidden field, and then call DeserializeJSON() to convert it into a coldfusion array.

Comment: @TRose I can't use predetermined values like Email1, etc... because it's indeterminate how many I need.  Some offices may have 1 contact but others may need 7 contacts.  It's totally random so I need to generate the field names dyamically.

Comment: @Redtopia  I would love it if <cfoutput>#form.[“CONTACT[1][CEMAIL]”]#</cfoutput> would work (that would have been easy), however, it unfortunately doesn't work.  Regarding "use JavaScript to create an array of the entries, pack it as JSON into a hidden field, and then call DeserializeJSON() to convert it into a coldfusion array", would you have a simple example (maybe for one of the fields) that I could see?

Comment: @PaulB I'm not saying to hard-code the names of the fields. You're obviously getting the iteration from `contactData.id` - why not just snap that on to the end of the `name` without all the fluff? So `name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cFirstName]` would turn into `name="'cFirstName' + contactData` and so on... and you could avoid this syntax nightmare.

Comment: @TRose I'm conceptually following what you're saying, I'm just not sure if I can translate that into JS.  Can you give me an example for this one field maybe?  Then I think I can probably make the additional changes.  Here's a snippet from the original JS:  '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
 ' <div class="form-group required">'+
 '  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cFirstName'+contactData.id+'" name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cFirstName]" value="'+contactData.cFirstName+'" placeholder="First Name" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+
 ' </div>'+

Comment: `name="contact['+contactData.id+'][cFirstName]"` should become `name="cFirstName' + contactData.id + '"'` - you may have to play with the placement of single quotes but your editor can help you with that. This will result in fieldnames like `cFirstName1` or `cFirstName2` that you should be able to loop through like you originally tried.

Comment: @Trose Okay it did take some playing but I finally got this to work:  '  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cFirstName'+contactData.id+'" name="cFirstName'+contactData.id+'" value="'+contactData.cFirstName+'" placeholder="First Name" data-rule-required="true" required="true">'+

Comment: @Paul B did you notice the quotes I added in my comment? That should work because those are the names of your form fields, and I can see those are the keys that CF is returning in your form scope.

Answer (score 1):

Since the author of this question (@Paul B) asked me for an example of how you can pass serialized javascript data to coldfusion on a form submission, and then iterate over it, here's an example of how that can be done.

**First, here's how I would output the form fields in ColdFusion:**

```
<cfset arr = [
    {
        firstName: "Brian",
        lastName: "Kelly"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Billy",
        lastName: "Short"
    }
];

<form id="myform" action="myhandler.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="mydata" id="myhiddenfield" />
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arr)#" index="ix">
        <div class="myform-item">
            <!---
            Group each element into a div, and the name of 
            each input are the same! This makes it easier to get
            their values on submit.
            --->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" value="#arr[ix].firstName#" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" data-index="#ix#">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value="#arr[ix].lastName#" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </cfloop>
</form>
```

**Next, here's the javascript... I'm using jQuery, but there are any number of ways to accomplish the same thing:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var form = $('#myForm');

    $(form).on('submit', function () {
        var items = [];
        $('div.myform-item', form).each(function (ix, item) {
            items.push({
                firstName: $('input[name="firstName"]', item).val(),
                lastName: $('input[name="firstName"]', item).val()
            });
        });
        $('#myhiddenfield').val(JSON.stringify(items));
    });

});
</script>
```

**And finally, here's the ColdFusion handler that will deserialize the JavaScript array into a native ColdFusion array:**

```
<cfscript>
// myhandler.cfm

try {

    param name="form.mydata"; // there will be other fields, but we don't care about them

    // do some basic validation... obviously this can be enhanced quite a bit
    if (!IsJSON(form.myData)) {
        throw();
    }

    myArray = DeserializeJSON(form.myData);
    
    if (!IsValid("array", myArray)) {
        throw();
    }

    // here's your array, now you can iterate over the array and do what you need to do
    dump(var=myArray);

} catch (any e) {
    dump(var=e);
}
</cfscript>
```